# Artifactory - custom base URL not working properly

Tags: artifactory

When I set the custom base url using the ui (`http://localhost:8082/ui/admin/configuration/general`), the only part that is considered is the ip address and protocol not the url path (`http://<server_address>:<port>/<path>`).

I notice that if I change the base url from `http://localhost:8082` to `http://test:8082` , requests done to `http://localhost:8081`  are directed to `http://test:8082` . However, when I add a path `http://localhost:8082/test/`  the requests are redirected redirected to `http://localhost:8082/ui` instead of `http://localhost:8082/test/ui`

Is there a way to change this behaviour?

I'm using artifactory 7.2.1

-**Edit**-

I'm trying to setup a reserve proxy where the base path will be `/app/artifactory`. Therefore, all requests made to `https://proxyhost/app/artifactory` should be mapped to http://artifactoryhost:8082. However, I can't make the UI query internal resources appropriately because the base path is ignored, even with the flag `X-JFrog-Override-Base-Url`

Comment: I think your best option would be adding a RP in front of your Artifactory server and setting the direction rules from there.

Comment: @Ortsigat, my problem is precisely with the RP setup. If the RP local path is any other than '/' the setup does not work because the base path is ignored.

Comment: Looks like this is not possible, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/62823429/2945062

Answer (score 0):

This seems to imply that if you use the full URL, the base redirect does not occur
https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-can-i-change-the-existing-base-url-of-artifactory/

> Option 3 (Bypass the redirect):
> Go to https://<ARTI_URL>/artifactory/webapp/#/login
> The system will not redirect you if you use the full URL.

Comment: Looks like you got similar answer from JFrog on your ticket.  https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-21689